# How to get the index of a value in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

What's the code to get the index of a value in a pandas series data structure?.

```
animals=pd.Series(['bear','dog','mammoth','python'], 
                  index=['canada','germany','iran','brazil'])
```

What's the code to extract the index of "mammoth"?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use boolean indexing:

```
In [8]: animals == 'mammoth'
Out[8]:
canada     False
germany    False
iran        True
brazil     False
dtype: bool

In [9]: animals[animals == 'mammoth'].index
Out[9]: Index(['iran'], dtype='object')
```

Note, indexes aren't necessarily unique for pandas data structures.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) If you make sure that value is unique, or just want to get the first one, use the find function.

```
find(animals, 'mammoth') #  retrieves index of first occurrence of value
```

2) If you would like to get all indices matching that value, as per @juanpa.arrivillaga 's post.

```
animals[animals == 'mammoth'].index # retrieves indices of all matching values
```

You can also index find any number occurrence of the  value by treating the the above statement as a list:

```
animals[animas == 'mammoth'].index[1] #retrieves index of second occurrence of value.
```

Comment: the `find` function?